# How to apply multiple filters with one searchbar and display those filters in the searchbar?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So here's my problem with my React app. I want to use a searchbar to select multiple filters on the data I display in my page. But you can only enter one string in a searchbar.
I'd like something a bit like this :
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eGBY.png)

Having a dropdown menu (just like with datalist) when clicking in the searchbar to select the key, then a dropdown to select the logical operator and then another one for the value. And the possibility to do it all again for an another filter (and so on...). And I would like to be able to discard each individual filter with an X icon on it. Obviously, I could create a different component for each part and give it and absolute position, on top of the searchbar... but that would be painful to display in a responsive way.

Any idea ?

Comment: Stack overflow isn't really for people to write code for you.  What have you attempted?

Comment: I'm not asking for someone to write code for me @RobertTerrell , don't worry. I'm just asking if there's any "simple" way to do it that I don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that is not what you want. But I recommend you to see following.
You can change for your purpose.

https://github.com/insin/react-filtered-multiselect

Comment: Thank you for taking the time but, indeed, it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I will have to create my own component I guess !